# How do I traverse this C data structure composed of multiple structs, arrays, and pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

```
typedef struct trans * Trans;

typedef struct state{
    int f;
    char  label[20];
    trans * TrasitionsArray[10];
}state;

struct trans{
    state * from;
    state * to;
    char  label;
};

void main(){
    state  StatesArray[100];
}
```

How can I give a value for (state---trasition---to---label)

I tried this but failed:

```
strcpy(StatesArray[i].TrasitionsArray[j]->to->label,"blahblah");
```

Comment: By the way, I think you mean "Transition", not "Trasition"

Comment: With all due respect, I think you need to spend some time - starting simple - with memory allocation and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state  StatesArray[100];` Will allocate only memory for structure members of state. It will allocate only 10 * 4 bytes(sizeof pointer in 32bit m/c) for `TrasitionsArray` to hold ten `Transition` structure variable. But memory is not allocated for members of `transition` structure variable. And similarly for `from` and `to` structure variable also.

Use the below sample code for allocation of internal pointer variables.

```
int i, j; 
struct state states[100]; 
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{     
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        StatesArray[i].TrasitionsArray[j] = (struct trans*)malloc(sizeof(struct trans));   
        StatesArray[i].TrasitionsArray[j]->from = (struct state *)malloc(sizeof(struct state));
        StatesArray[i].TrasitionsArray[j]->to = (struct state *)malloc(sizeof(struct state));
    }
}
```

Note : Take care of `NULL` check for the return value of `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you only allocated an array of `state`s. The `state` structure has a pointer to an array of `trans`, but you never allocated that array.

After the line where you allocate the `StatesArray` array, you need to iterate over that array and allocate memory and values to the `TransitionsArray` elements in each `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate some memory first. All pointers to arrays are not initialized.

```
int i, j;
struct state states[100];
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    states.transitionsArray = (struct trans*)malloc(sizeof(struct trans)*10);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        // set 'from' and 'to' pointers here
    }
}
```

Btw: I assumed that you meant `struct trans * trasitionsArray;`